# How to count max consistent activity days for each users (ID)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a DataFrame in Python like this:

[image]

```
ID  Day      Turnover Activity
333 01-01-20 598      1
333 02-01-20 5435     1
333 03-01-20 665      1
333 04-01-20 0        0
333 05-01-20 0        0
777 01-01-20 323      1
777 02-01-20 121      1
777 03-01-20 734      1
777 04-01-20 831      1
777 05-01-20 0        0

#explanation
if Turnover > 0:
    Activity = 1
else:
    Activity = 0
```

But there are a lot of other `ID` with 0 or >0 values in the `Turnover` column in the full DataFrame.
So. I would like to count max amount of consistent `1` for each `ID`.
How can I do that, please?

Best regards!

Comment: I would like to count max amount of consistent "1" for each "ID". what does this mean, could you please post your expected output.

Comment: Hi. I've updated the picture. Please)

Comment: @btnvstusrnm, it's always helps when you paste a sample of the data. It's difficult to reproduce your problem with an image!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add couple of extra columns to achieve what you wanted to achieve.

```
df = df.sort_values(["ID", "Day"])
df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Day).astype('int64')
df["Change"] = df.Activity.diff().fillna(1)
df["StartTimeStamp"] = df.Change * df.Timestamp
df["StartTimeStamp"] = df.StartTimeStamp.replace(0, method='ffill')
summary = df[df.StartTimeStamp > 0].groupby(["ID", "StartTimeStamp"]).Activity.count().groupby("ID").max()
```

Comment: It's perfect and works! You're amazing genius! Thanks a lot!